# Calculate line segment in Intersection

Tags: qgis

I am working with the Geoscience tool bar in QGIS to desurvey drill holes, and I need to calculate the amount of drilling done within each claim cell, however some of the drill stems cross the claim boundary. I can see where the drill stem crosses the claim boundary when using the 'intersection' tool, but I would like to know if there is a way to calculate what portion of the drill stem lies within the intersection portion. It will give me the information on the entire drillhole, but not which portion lies within the intersection data. Yes, I can measure the line length, but these are 3D lines below surface, so the measure features do not account for this, they only measure the surface projection, and I need the downhole length.

See photo.. the yellow selected portion is the claim, and the dashed black lines are the drill stems I need the lengths for, but only the lengths within the claim boundary.[image: See how the drill stems cross the claim boundary.. how do I calculate that 3D length]

Comment: So the drill holes arent straight?

Comment: Clip the drill holes by the claim polygon feature?